# Endomorphism ring of the Jacobian of a generic smooth plane quartic

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, abelian-varieties, jacobians

Let $C$ be an arbitrary smooth plane quartic defined over a number field $K$. Assume $C$ is not hyperelliptic, and denote by $J$ the Jacobian of $C$. How does $\text{End}(J)$ look like for a generic curve $C$?

Comment: A smooth plane quartic is never hyperelliptic.

Comment: (More generally, the gonality of a smooth plane curve of degree $d$ is $d-1$, given by projection from a point on the curve. This is due to Max Noether.)

Comment: $\operatorname{End}(A)=\mathbb{Z} $ for a general principally polarized abelian variety of dimension $g$, hence in particular when $A$ is the Jacobian of a general plane quartic.

Comment: Dear @abx, do you have any reference for this statement? I couldn't find one.

Comment: One reference (giving actually the result for a generic Jacobian, in any characteristic) is: S. Mori,  *The endomorphism rings of some abelian varieties*,  Japan. J. Math. **2**, no. 1 (1976). There is probably a simpler reference for complex abelian varieties.

Answer (score 1):

See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0405156 where Del Pezzo surfaces of degree 2 are used, in order to construct plane quartics, whose jacobians have endomorphism ring $\mathbb{Z}$.